# pymongo 3.4.0 connecting to mongo atlas

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I have python 2.7, have pymongo 3.4

and im trying to connect to mongo atlas using the following :

```
import certifi
import ssl
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient


MongoClient(
    "mongodb://Admin:<PASSWORD>@ABC-shard-00-00-XYZ:27017",
    "ABC-shard-00-01-XYZ:27017",
    "ABC-shard-00-02-XYZ:27017/dev?ssl=true&replicaSet=ABC-0&authSource=admin",
    ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
    ssl_ca_certs=certifi.where()
)
```

it keeps failing with Authentication failed. code 18

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [Using PyMongo with MongoDB Atlas](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/atlas.html):

Since [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) v3.4.0, you can connect to [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) by passing the [Connection String URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) provided by MongoDB Atlas to [MongoClient](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient), example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@ABC-cluster-shard-00-00-XYZ.mongodb.net:27017,ABC-cluster-shard-00-01-XYZ.mongodb.net:27017,ABC-cluster-shard-00-02-XYZ.mongodb.net:27017/DATABASE?ssl=true&replicaSet=ABC-cluster-shard-0&authSource=admin")
```

Connections to MongoDB Atlas require [TLS/SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). With PyMongo 3.3+, you can install PyMongo 3.3+ and any TLS/SSL-related dependencies using the following [Python pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) command:

```
python -m pip install pymongo[tls]
```